# How to insert array of json by psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

My table structure is

```
 --------------------
|      testtable     |
 --------------------
|  col name  |  type |
 --------------------
| id         | text  |
| data       | json[]|
 --------------------
```

My code

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json

insertdata = {"id": "001", "data": [Json({"foo": 1}), Json({"foo": 2})]}
print(type(insertdata["data"][0]))

cur.execute("insert into testtable values(%(id)s, %(data)s)", insertdata)
```

Result says my data is **list of text** but surely it is **psycopg2._json.Json**. What data type should I convert to?

```
<class 'psycopg2._json.Json'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    cur.execute("insert into testtable values(%(id)s, %(data)s)", insertdata)
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "data" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: insert into testtable values('001', ARRAY['{"foo": 1}','{"fo...
                                            ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [answer](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/discussions/1466#discussioncomment-2981517) from psycopg team

> Looking at mogrify:
>
> ```py
> print(cur.mogrify("%(data)s", insertdata).decode()) 
> ARRAY['{"foo": 1}','{"foo": 2}']
> ```
>
> The adapter for the json wrapper doesn't add a cast to the snippet it generates, so it's passed as "unknown" to the parser. Postgres can cast unknown -> json, but, because there isn't a type such as "unknown array" (there is "anyarray", but it's only a pseudotype to be used as parameter type, I don't think it can be really instantiated), the array is temporarily converted to a text array. Because there isn't an implicit text[] -> json[] cast, automatic cast fails.
>
> You can cast the expression, as suggested, using
>
> ```
> cur.execute("insert into testtable values(%(id)s, %(data)s::json[])", insertdata)
> ```
>
> Note that psycopg 3 has a more refine adaptation system, able to figure out the type of the parameter, and the query above doesn't require an explicit cast.